# Select persons in the order of latest message they sent or recieved

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to make a chat system. It has got 2 tables(chats , users) with the following schema. Chat Table
[image: User Table Schema]

User Table
[image: User Table Schema]

I want to select all users that a person chatted with according to the latest message between any 2 users. 

Example:
Consider I have a user called X and he/she has chatted with A, B, C, D. I have to first find A, B, C, D from Chat Table(i.e all the users who has chatted with person X). Then for each user A, B, C, D, find the ChatDateTime of the latest message they sent or received from X and sort A, B, C, D according to it.

The chat table looks like this:

```
+--------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| ChatId | FromUserId | ToUserId | ChatText | ChatDateTime |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| 1      | 2          | 3        | hai      | 12:30        |
| 2      | 3          | 2        | hello    | 12:34        |
| 3      | 3          | 2        | I am X   | 12:38        |
| 4      | 1          | 3        | I am A   | 12:40        |
| 5      | 2          | 3        | I am B   | 12:41        |
| 6      | 4          | 3        | I am C   | 12:42        |
| 7      | 5          | 3        | I am D   | 12:44        |
| 8      | 3          | 4        | Hai 'C'  | 12:50        |
+--------+------------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

Here UserId's are A=1,B=2,X=3,C=4,D=5. From the table, we understand that X(UserId=3) has chatted with A, B, C, D (which should be selected first). The Latest conversation is between C and X (ChatId-8). So the first result should be C. Then D(ChatId-7), then B(ChatId-5) and finally A(ChatId-4). So the order of selection should be C, D, B, A.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us sample data for the problem.

Comment: show your db query ..

Comment: No pictures thanks. Just paste the formatted text here, using the code formatting button, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Okay.Changed.

Comment: I also posted a link. If the answers below fail to address your problem, it would be great if you could take a look at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserID AS UserID,
       latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserName AS UserName,
       latestChatDateTime AS latestChatDateTime,
       otherUserID AS otherUserID,
       User.UserName AS otherUserName
FROM ( SELECT User.UserID AS UserID,
              User.UserName AS UserName,
              CASE
                  WHEN User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID THEN
                      Chat.ToUserID
                  ELSE
                      Chat.FromUserID
              END AS otherUserID,
              MAX( ChatDateTime ) AS latestChatDateTime
       FROM User
       JOIN Chat ON User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID
                 OR User.UserID = Chat.ToUserID
       GROUP BY User.UserID,
                otherUserID
     ) AS latestChatDateTimeFinder
JOIN User ON latestChatDateTimeFinder.otherUserID = User.UserID
ORDER BY latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserID,
         otherUserID;
```

This statement starts with the following subquery...

```
SELECT User.UserID AS UserID,
       User.UserName AS UserName,
       CASE
           WHEN User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID THEN
               Chat.ToUserID
           ELSE
               Chat.FromUserID
       END AS otherUserID,
       MAX( ChatDateTime ) AS latestChatDateTime
FROM User
JOIN Chat ON User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID
          OR User.UserID = Chat.ToUserID
GROUP BY User.UserID,
         otherUserID
```

This subquery performs an `INNER JOIN` between `User` and `Chat` based on whichever of `FromUserID` or `ToUserID` shares a value with `UserID`.

It then selects the fields.  The `CASE` statement will choose the other `UserID` based on the shared values established by the `JOIN`.

The resulting dataset is then grouped by the two `UserID` values and the most recent date corresponding to the combination of those two values is selected via the `MAX()` function.

This will give us a list of each user and each other user they have corresponded with along with the datetime of the most recent correspondence.

This list is then joined to `User` in the main statement based on the now identified `UserID` value for the other User to allow for the appendage of that User's name to the dataset.

The fields are then chosen from the dataset, given aliases and sorted.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Appendix*

To limit the results to those for one `User` and all of those that they have corresponded with, please try either...

```
SELECT latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserID AS UserID,
       latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserName AS UserName,
       latestChatDateTime AS latestChatDateTime,
       otherUserID AS otherUserID,
       User.UserName AS otherUserName
FROM ( SELECT User.UserID AS UserID,
              User.UserName AS UserName,
              CASE
                  WHEN User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID THEN
                      Chat.ToUserID
                  ELSE
                      Chat.FromUserID
              END AS otherUserID,
              MAX( ChatDateTime ) AS latestChatDateTime
       FROM User
       JOIN Chat ON ( User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID OR
                      User.UserID = Chat.ToUserID )
                AND User.UserID = targetUser
       GROUP BY otherUserID
     ) AS latestChatDateTimeFinder
JOIN User ON latestChatDateTimeFinder.otherUserID = User.UserID
ORDER BY otherUserID;
```

... or...

```
SELECT latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserID AS UserID,
       latestChatDateTimeFinder.UserName AS UserName,
       latestChatDateTime AS latestChatDateTime,
       otherUserID AS otherUserID,
       User.UserName AS otherUserName
FROM ( SELECT User.UserID AS UserID,
              User.UserName AS UserName,
              CASE
                  WHEN User.UserID = Chat.FromUserID THEN
                      Chat.ToUserID
                  ELSE
                      Chat.FromUserID
              END AS otherUserID,
              MAX( ChatDateTime ) AS latestChatDateTime
       FROM User
       JOIN Chat ON User.UserID = targetUser
                AND User.UserID = targetUser
       GROUP BY otherUserID
     ) AS latestChatDateTimeFinder
JOIN User ON latestChatDateTimeFinder.otherUserID = User.UserID
ORDER BY otherUserID;
```

Please note that that `targetUser` (the value used to refer to the `User` in question) can be either an explicit value or a variable.

Comment: This answer is almost what I wanted. The query finds the latest conversation for all users in the users table. But I wanted to find only the conversation of one user with every other user in the users table. So the `users.UserID` remains fixed in my case.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad to be of help.  Please note, I have modified my Answer with a couple of variations that should limit the results to those for just one `User`.

Answer (score 0):

**First part** - 
 all the users who has chatted with person X

**Second part**
 all the users related to this user

I have made the union of these two parts

```
 select u.UserName,c.toUserId  from userTable u inner join chatTable c where UserID IN (select toUserId from chatTable where fromUserId = 'X' order by ChatDateTime desc ) 
UNION ALL
select u.UserName,c.toUserId  from userTable u inner join chatTable c where UserID IN (select fromUserId from chatTable where fromUserId = 'X' order by ChatDateTime desc )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sometime like this

```
select max(chatdatetime) as chatdatetime,sec_user from
(select chatid,chatdatetime,
  case when fromuserid='X' then touserid
       when touserid='X' then fromuserid 
  end as sec_user
 from chat 
where fromuserid='X' or touserid='X'
) t
 group by sec_user
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
SELECT t.Id, MAX(t.ChatDateTime) FROM
(SELECT FromUserId AS Id, ChatDateTime FROM Chat
WHERE ToUserId = X
UNION
SELECT ToUserId As Id, ChatDateTime FROM Chat
WHERE FromUserId = X) As t
GROUP BY t.Id
ORDER BY t.ChatDateTime DESC
```